# PHP persistent referer

Tags: php

In my app, I have a few forms that can be accessed from different urls in the app. Each form has a cancel button, that should return the user from the url that they previously came from.

So, this is pretty easy to achieve with $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].

The problem comes into being when the user submits the form, and it fails validation. So, at that point, the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is the form itself. Obviously, the cancel button wont work properly then, since the original referer has now been 'lost'.

What is the best way around this? Should I be storing the original referer in the session, or perhaps via a hidden form field? Or perhaps there is another more elegant method?

Comment: How does the cancel button work at the moment? Javascript, form submission etc>

Comment: Just a plain old hyperlink in most cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the referrer for this, Use a different method. Maybe set some session variable yourself with 'last visited page' or use hidden field to save back page url.

Answer (score 1):

The best method which will always guarantee the user gets back to the same place despite multiple tabs/windows would be to pass the return URL as a GET param.

Answer (score 0):

You can save it as a cookie pretty easily
http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php

Using url encode and passing it in the query string or post data is the other way but then you have to keep track of it.